# How to calculate a 256-bit HMAC_SHA3 hash with CryptoJS?

Tags: hash, sha, hmac, cryptojs

Recent CryptoJS versions support SHA3 hashing.

SHA3 can output different hash sizes, including 512-bit (default) and 256-bit. These two work fine:

```
var sha3_512_hash = CryptoJS.SHA3( 'test' );
var sha3_256_hash = CryptoJS.SHA3( 'test' , { outputLength:256 } );
```

Similarly, CryptoJS can also calculate HMAC values. However, I can't figure out how to change the default output size there:

```
var sha3_512_hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA3( 'test' , 'key' );
var sha3_256_hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA3( 'test' , 'key' , { outputLength:256 } );
```

The first works OK (the result is a 512-bit hmac value) but the second is the *same* (i.e. also 512-bit), as if it ignores the {outputLength:256} parameter!

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/M8xf3/ (using hmac-sha3.js from CryptoJS 3.1.2)

Does anyone know how to create 256-bit SHA3-based HMAC hashes?

P.S. For the SHA2 family of functions, CryptoJS has separate Hmac functions for each output size (that's HmacSHA256 and HmacSHA512). But this doesn't seem to be the case for SHA3?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the actual question, but note that with SHA3 you don't really need HMAC hashes. Unlike SHA1 and SHA2 and MD5, SHA3 is *not* vulnerable to length-extension attacks.

Therefore with SHA3 it would suffice to just prepend or append the secret key to your input.

Or, if you're paranoid of a single hash step becoming compromised (not to be expected in the foreseeable future, especially not with SHA3, but still) you could do something like SHA3(key+SHA3(key+data)) or SHA3(key+SHA3(key+data)+data) (obviously with "+" denoting binary concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit hmac-sha3.js and change the outputLength to 256-bit instead of 512-bit.

1. Open hmac-sha3.js file, using your text editor.
2. Find "{outputLength:512}" and replace it with "{outputLength:256}"

Then the hash output will be 256-bit in length.

To be sure that you did not messed up things, double check your 256-bit hmac-sha3 output with some test cases available on the internet, for example: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/hmac_sha3_testvectors.html